# number with no quotation in php

Tags: php

the php code is pretty simple :

```
<?php

$my_bn_num=number_bangla(0123);

function number_bangla($num1){
echo ("<br>num =".$num1);
}

?>
```

And the ouput is: num=83

But if I call the function with a singly quoted string like this:

```
$my_bn_num=number_bangla('0123');
```

the output is: num=0123

What is the detailed difference between 0123 and '0123' here ?

Comment: 0123 is an octal no. and '0123' is a string

Comment: no 0123 is an integer. If you want to treat 0123 as an integer then u have to use type conversion. Like this (int)0123

Comment: You might want to change `echo ("<br>num =".$num1);` to `return "<br>num =".$num1;` and add `echo $my_bn_num;` at the end, unless I'm seeing this wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0123 is a numeric value whereas '0123' is a string value. Internally PHP stores those types differently.

In order to cast string to integer you can do following:

```
$num = (int) $num;
```

In this particular example printing number 0123 results to 83 because 0123 is an octal value. For casting octal strings to octal numbers PHP offers octdec() function:

```
$num = octdec($num);
```

Comment: if 0123 is a numeric value, then why should the output be 83? is it coz as munjal said that  0123 is octal>

Comment: because 0123 is an octal value

Comment: can't a decimal number begin with a zero ?

Comment: nope, PHP detects such numbers and treats them accordingly i.e. it converts it to decimal automatically and decimal numbers can't start with zero.

Comment: seems to be strange.. in real life, no leading zeros are necessary for a decimal number but if there is any , that can also be a decimal number

Answer (score 2):

0123 is an octal integer because it starts with 0.
Integers will be printed by echo/print as decimal numbers.

'0123' is a string, so nothing will be converted when it is printed.

Comment: can't a decimal number start with a 0?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: 0123 means 123 in octal(so 83 in decimal, and 83 printed)

Answer (score 0):

0123 is an octal number.  In most scripting languages any number represented by a 0 in front of it is treated as if it were an octal number (since you normally don't put 0's in front of numbers.

When you specify it in quotes its treated as a string.

When you are handling integers and want them in a particular format, what you should do is use the [intval](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function.

`intval($num,10)` would translate the variable `$num` to a base-10 integer, instead of relying on the PHP casting code to work its black magic.